# Set body height to full window height

Tags: html, css, height

I want to make `<body>` with 100% of the page height.

When I use 100% or 100vh on both `<html>` and `<body>`, they don't extend when the page content overflows the viewport.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

When I use `min-height: 100%;` for `<body>` instead of `height: 100%;`, it does extend, but then I cannot use percentage height for divs inside the body, since the body does not have the height set.

How to make the body "infinite" and still be able to use divs with percentage inside it?

Comment: Use both `height: 100vh` and `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: @Turnip Then it doesn't change the height after scrolling, because it's exactly set to 100vh.

Comment: That is not true. The body will extend to accomodate it's content. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/um0wor5p/4/

Comment: Using my example, should the div be 50% of the height of the viewport or 50% of the height of the entire document?

Comment: 50% of the body = 50% of the whole document. That's what I'd like. But for some reason the body height is staying at 100vh for me.

Comment: Ok, I set the min-height of the body to 100vh. It does extend, but I still cannot use the divs with percentage height, because the height of the body isn't defined. I guess it just isn't possible. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want isn't possible and more precisely not logical. let's ask a trivial question:

> What will define the height of the body?

1) you want your `body` to be `height:100%` of the screen: You can either use a cascading `height:100%` or `height:100vh` and your `body` will have an explicit specified height thus you can use percentage height inside it but the body won't grow more than `100%`.

2) you want your `body` to be `min-height:100%` of the screen: You can use either `min-height:100vh` or `min-height:100%` while having `height:100%` set to `html`. In this case, **the content of the body** will define the real height as you simply added a `min-height` constraint. If you have a lot of content, the body will grow beyond the `100%` limit, if not you will have it at `100%`. In this situation, it's clear that the content cannot use percentage value within height since the content is defining the body height.

You can have either (1) or (2) but you cannot have both since there is no logical way to define a `min-height` to the body, allow it to grow (depending on its content) and allow its content to use percentage values within height.